# How do I share a link and photo with Instagram using PHP

Tags: php, photo, sharing, instagram

How do I share a link and photo with Instagram using PHP? I can't find anything for "share photo with instagram".

Comment: Thank me later http://instagram.com/developer/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By "share photo with instagram", do you mean that you are trying to post a picture to Instagram via PHP? You cannot post pictures to Instagram via the API.