# Post pictures to Instagram through API

Tags: instagram

I want to post pictures to [Instagram](https://instagram.com) from my web application, but found that currently it is not possible through the API.

But I found the [posts.so](https://posts.so/) website is able to do that.

How are they doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post pictures to instagram using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible from the API, according to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api).

I think they have connections to the instagram and that is how they did it.