# Instagram API hacked to allow uploads?

Tags: php, api, instagram

According to this press release: https://madmimi.com/p/7a2394?fe=1&pact=23816224659#, 
this company can upload directly to Instagram.

I thought uploading to Instagram's API was not allowed? Does any one know how this is done?

Comment: Instagram private API? I was looking for the same thing, couldn't find any hopeful results rather than a GitHub repository [phpinstagram](https://github.com/gruzilla/phpinstagram)

Comment: If you run wireshark while gramblr is logging in and uplaoding, you should be able to read the packets to determine how they are doing it.

Comment: Here's a python library that claims to be able to do it, but
"The key needed to sign the requests has been purposely omitted."
https://github.com/acoomans/instagram-client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Instagram's API documentation:

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons...

While it is possible to use Instagram's private API to upload photos (you'd need to capture this information using a proxy server) it is a very quick way to get you instantly banned for life from using the API.

There are a handful of exceptions to this rule, Hipstamatic/Oggl being one of them. Whether or not posts.so is or not, I can't say, though I find it highly unlikely that they're authorized to do that they're doing. More-so with gramblr, their site is.. shady at best.

Comment: I read the API docs, yes there is a exception list while Gramblr is not in it, Good answer though ;)

Comment: So are you suggesting this company is using the same kind of hack that Gramblr is using?

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot post pictures to Instagram via the API.

See : [How to post pictures to instagram using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api)

Comment: According to the press release in the original question, this company claims to be able to do it.