# Post to Instagram with .NET

Tags: .net, instagram

I know there have already been some questions about this, but they were a time ago and I didn't find anything else on the internet (or I didn't searched enough). I know also that the API doesn't support it, but maybe somebody already found a way arround that?

But is there already a way to post to Instagram programmatically with .NET?

I saw the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api) of PHP where somebody was able to login and post a picture to a account. But I was wondering if there was already found a way to do it in .NET. I would prefer a solution where you don't have to log in with the user-pass, but maybe would be able to do it with the generated access_token.

I'm building an application where it's the meaning to post to different kinds of (social) media. Facebook And Twitter are no problem with their own API. But I think it's sad that Instagram doesn't allow programmers to post. I know their reasons, but still.. (Didn't started with Pinterest yet, but at first sight there API isn't that good as Facebook as well?)

Getting the access_token is no hard work at all, but basically you can only get posts that you didn't create with your own application. So it would be nice to post too!

Thx!

Comment: Are you aware of [InstaSharp](http://instasharp.org/)?  I have not used it but I think it is worth looking at for your requirement.

Comment: I was aware of it indeed. But I saw that it was build on top of the official API. Here I found the Media Endpoint and saw that there also wasn't a way to post :( 
https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp/blob/master/src/InstaSharp/Endpoints/Media.cs