# post pictures on my website automaticly post on instagram via api

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

i need guidance about Instagram API.i have a website where users can post pictures.and it should be post on Instagram (For Instagram user) automatically(From my website).on Instagram a link show my website (Where actually  picture is posted ) .Is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked up the documentation? Have you visited this site: https://instagram.com/developer/

Comment: the answer is no. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api

Comment: yes i have looked up the documentation but i cannot find my answer.Facebook have this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot upload photos to Instagram from your website or through their API. You are required to upload pictures only from their mobile apps.

From Instagram's API documentation https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/:

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> - Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app.
> - We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the
>     Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to
>     ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our
>     platform.