# Post images from Unity to Instagram?

Tags: instagram-api, unity-game-engine

I would like to know if its possible to post images to Instagram from Unity, like a screenshot. So far I tried to look through google to find something on this topic but had no luck. Unity asset store has only paid plugins. I would like to have possibility to do this on iOS and Android. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post pictures to instagram using API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api)

Answer (score 4):

There is no instagram API at the time of this answer which allows you to post photos from outside the app

[Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Instagram api https://www.instagram.com/developer/ this should give you a method to do it