# How to post photo to instagram using js?

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

I know that there is no api function to send the photo. But maybe there are some methods to do this from JS?

Comment: Have you tried something yourself?

Comment: @C0dekid, no, just look to the api documentation. you know the solution?

Comment: No, I don't think this can be done with javascript only.

Comment: @C0dekid, I watched [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api). But I do not want to use PHP

Comment: The instagram API requires `PHP Curl` if you want to do it with your website. So technically you have to use PHP if you want to use the API for your website. You can combine `PHP` and `Javascript` together with the `$.ajax()` function in `jQuery`. So javascript only can't be done, i'm sorry.

Comment: @C0dekid, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Now Instagram does allow [Content Publishing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/) from their API.

Example from docs:

#### API Example

Let's say you have a photo at `https://www.example.com/images/bronz-fonz.jpg` that you want to publish with the hashtag "#BronzFonz" as its caption. You could use the `POST /{ig-user-id}/media` endpoint to create the container like this:

**Sample Request**

```
POST graph.facebook.com/17841400008460056/media
  ?image_url=https//www.example.com/images/bronz-fonz.jpg
  &caption=#BronzFonz
```

This would return a container ID (let's say `17889455560051444`), which you would then publish using the `POST /{ig-user-id}/media_publish` endpoint, like this:

**Sample Request**

```
POST graph.facebook.com/17841405822304914/media_publish
  ?creation_id=17889455560051444
```

Wrapping those with JS shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'user',
  target: "instafeed-container",
  resolution: 'low_resolution',
  accessToken: 'your generated token'
});
userFeed.run();
```

```css
a img {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Instafeed on Your Website</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/stevenschobert/instafeed.js@2.0.0rc1/src/instafeed.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 style="text-align: center">Instagram Feed</h1>
  <div id="instafeed-container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.