# How to upload or post a photo in instagram without instagram app in mobile device

Tags: javascript

Upload the photo to specific instagram user wall  used media/upload API is deprecated .I need to know any other api can post the photo in specific user instagram wall

Comment: [Check it out dude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api)

Comment: `POST https://instagram.com/api/v1/media/upload/`

Check this code for example https://code.google.com/p/twitubas/source/browse/common/instagram.php