# Slack and Instagram direct integration

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, slack-api, slack

Could you please help to figure out: is there any way to receive messages from instagram direct to slack and send response back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only partly. You can retrieve message from Instagramm and post them on Slack, but the Instagramm API does not allow posting new objects on Instagramm (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api)).

For the implementation I see two approaches to implement your requirement:

1. Use [IFTT](https://ifttt.com/). Both Slack and Instagramm are available on IFTT and you can most likely set up forwarding of messages to Slack and vice versa. Would not even require any coding. However the IFTT rules are usually somewhat limited, so depening on what you want to do exactly you might need to accept some compromised.
2. Build a small script (e.g. with PHP) to retrieve messages from Instagramm (e.g. with [get recent media endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self)) and send them to Slack (e.g. with [incomming webhook](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks)).