# Ruby on Rails - post images to Instagram

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to post an image to Instagram with Ruby on Rails with gem [instagram](https://github.com/facebookarchive/instagram-ruby-gem).

I can get my own `access_token`.

And `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` works well for me.

But I cannot find the way to post an image via instagram apis.

So please help me if any experience with instagram apis. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [it is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18844791/2039726) to post an image with Instagram API. Their API supports almost only GET calls (except adding a like, comment or relationship).

You can check all endpoints here: [Instagram API Docs](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

Comment: It was previously possible and still seems to be allowed for select clients like HootSuite. I'm guessing the POST endpoints where removed to combat spambots.

Comment: @max HootSuite and the other applications, they're not automatically, just remindering me to post images `by myself` and `manually` on mobile app - instagram. It's not what i am trying. anw thank you.

Comment: They did actually post straight to Instagram at one point, but I guess the endpoint has been removed completely. For mobile apps you still have “intents” which is what you are describing.

Comment: @Dapeng114 how are you going with this? I am working on using this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/content-publishing/#publish-photos