# I can not send photos to Instagram

Tags: php

i'm used this script https://github.com/LookHin/instagram-photo-video-upload-api
and send photo to instagram .

at first it was all okay, but now i have error

```
{"message": "checkpoint_required", "checkpoint_url": "https://i.instagram.com/challenge/7802983840/9pgObzPwlG/", "lock": true, "status": "fail", "error_type": "checkpoint_challenge_required"}
```

This problem show now after every starting script and press button "its me" Does not help.
HOW to fix ?

Comment: Add your codes.

Comment: You have the response and the exact error. It would be better to consult the documentation.

Comment: Did you make sure you disabled two-factor authentication?

Comment: yes, disabled  .

Comment: `checkpoint_challenge_required` the server seems to be actively denying you because you are not authenticated.

Answer (score -2):

You should use the official [api of Instagram](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) because the Api that you use in an unofficial one and it's a prohibited way to post media on Instagram.

**But I've just seen that**

> The Content Publishing API is in closed beta with Facebook Marketing Partners and Instagram Partners only. We are not accepting new applicants at this time.

So tha Instagram Graph Api **is not the solution**

I look on stack overflow and I found that :

> You cannot post pictures to Instagram via the API.

[Know more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api)