# Error posting photo or video with Instagram Web Api

Tags: http-post, instagram

When I publish the https://www.instagram.com/media/configure/ I get a forbidden error (403)

i upload the photo ----->

```
theUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/rupload_igphoto/" + entityName;
xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("x-instagram-rupload-params",
        media_type: 1,
        upload_id: Date.now(),
        upload_media_height: _img.height,
        upload_media_width: _img.width
    }));
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Entity-Name", entityName);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(
'X-Entity-Length', chunkSize,
);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(
'Offset', 0,
);
```

<----- result 200

media configure ----->

```
  theUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/create/configure/";
  xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send(
    'upload_id=' + _upload_id + '&caption=testing&usertags=&custom_accessibility_caption=&retry_timeout='
  )
```

<----- result eror 403

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post pictures to instagram using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the X-CSRFToken in the RequestHeader.

ex:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "your token");
```

HTTP's 403 Forbidden client error response code is the same as the one the server sends to Indicates that the request was understood, but the authentication was rejected.

This status is similar to the 401, but in this case re-authenticating will not change the result. Access has been permanently banned, such as you lack permission to access the resource. It is tied to the logic of the application.