# How to add instagram picture post url links to anchor tag?

Tags: html

I'm creating sample html page and use social sharing functionalities.
I want to instagram photo post url to share photo, like whatsapp text share url given below.

```
//whatsapp text share url
<a href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=whatsappphonenumber&text='></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want to do but Instagram doesn't allow people to post photos using api in their platform.

Comment: i mean we can post photo, text etc like in facebook , the same thing i want to photo post in instagram.

Comment: It is not actually possible on Instagram.  Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api